# How to count values from a dropdown Menu in sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a gsheet with a in-cell dropdown column and 3 options, `a,b,c`.
My sheet has 1000 rows of which I chose options for over 200 of them. Now I want to count how many times I've chosen `a` but using `=COUNTIF(L:L,"a")` doesn't work.

Here is an example of what I mean:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZYTv1mRo9z531hSSlfsUBZosJiOXZ-_LcIo0amNwBoE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This `=COUNTIF(B:B,"a")` works for me in your given sheet.

Answer (score 1):

try perhaps:

```
=COUNTIF(L:L, "*a*")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me:

```
=COUNTIF(L:L;"a")
```

Switch the comma for a semi colon.